# Can't generate android manifest properly

Tags: android

I can't generate android manifest properly.

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Islamqa\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: resource 
mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.mayazaal.Islamic.Questions.Answer.bangla:mipmap/ic_launcher)
not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

Comment: Make sure that  you have `ic_launcher.xml` within you `minimap` folder.

Comment: Please reformat you question (mark `code`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `MyProject/res/mipmap-bn_BD/ic_launcher.png`